# video.js module Experiencing an error message after install

Tags: 8, media

I am using Drupal 8 and attempting to set up the [video.js module](https://www.drupal.org/project/videojs). The readme file needs work so it's hard to know where I went wrong.

Here is what I've done so far:

1. installed the module using composer.
2. went to the [video.js GitHub](https://github.com/videojs/video.js) and downloaded the js and placed it in the drupal 8 libraries folder path of libraries/video-js/video.js (not what's listed in the readme file since that said sites/all/libraries, which is a d7 location).
3. added the video.js to my content type field settings.

I receive this error message overlay on the video player:

> No compatible source was found for this video.

The video was shot with an iPhone 8 and uploaded using the video module field.

Comment: What extension is your video file? Dot what?

Comment: .mov shot on from my iPhone 8

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a bug report or support request to a third-party dependency hosted on drupal.org or elsewhere and therefore must be reported there to track issues at a single place, not on Drupal Answers.

Comment: Try with a .mp4 file and see what happens.

Comment: To @leymanmx just because I can’t get it working f doesn’t meant it’s a bug........ this is a common error and it’s usually a setup problem that causes it.... not a bug.... and no sssweat, Same issue with .mp4. Im also looking for maximum compatibility. So users can upload most standard format types and be successful.

Comment: Check if the video file exists somewhere inside the /sites/default/files folder. You could possibly have a permission issue that is not allowing Drupal the write to the /files folder.

Comment: @nosssweat the files are being Written to that directory and if I select the autoplay option the video plays. But while playing there’s still the error written on top of the video with a big X as well.